# What is the uniqueidentifier (default newid()) was inserted?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with a uniqueidentifier and NEWID() default for new records. Executed the insert script. How do I know what uniqueidentifier was generated for the Id column since the last insert?

Table Script

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyData](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Data] [varbinary](max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyData] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_MyData_Id]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [Id]
GO
```

Insert Script

```
INSERT INTO dbo.MyData (Data)
VALUES (NULL)
GO
```

What is the uniqueidentifier was inserted?

Answer (score 2):

Use an `OUTPUT` clause. I `INSERT` the data into a table variable so that is it can consumed by other statements afterwards:

```sql
DECLARE @IDs table (ID uniqueidentifier);

INSERT INTO dbo.MyData
OUTPUT inserted.Id
INTO @IDs
DEFAULT VALUES;

SELECT *
FROM @IDs;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no particular value in relying on the default in your example.

Just create a scalar variable of type `uniqueidentifier` and assign it the result of  `NEWID` yourself

```
DECLARE @Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NEWID();

INSERT INTO dbo.MyData (Id)
VALUES (@Id);
```

This is more concise than having to insert into a table variable and subsequently select from it.